# Enable only first and third wednesday for each month in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Using the [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), I'm trying to enable users to choose only **first** and **third** Wednesdays of each month.

For now, the only thing I've managed to do is to enable only Wednesdays, by passing it in the options. 
Does anyone know if I can pass my "first and third" wanted configuration as an option, and how?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.bootstrap-date-picker').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'fr',
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,1,2,4,5,6],
            format: "ll",
            minDate: moment(),
            icons:
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enableddates) option to enable single dates instead of `daysOfWeekDisabled`.

You can create an helper function that returns an array with the first and the third Wednesday of a given month using momentjs. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278588/4131048).

You can add a listner for [`dp.update`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpupdate) to update your enabled dates (using [`enabledDates`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisableddates) function) when the user changes month.

Here a complete working example:

```js
function getFirstAndThirdWed(year, month){
    // Convert date to moment (month 0-11)
    var myMonth = moment({year: year, month: month});
    // Get first Wednesday of the first week of the month
    var firstWednesday = myMonth.weekday(2);
    // Check if first Wednesday is in the given month
    if( firstWednesday.month() != month ){
        firstWednesday.add(1, 'weeks');
    }
    // Get 3rd Wednesday of the month
    var third = firstWednesday.clone().add(2, 'weeks');
    return [firstWednesday, third];
}

$('.bootstrap-date-picker').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'fr',
  useCurrent: false,
  enabledDates: getFirstAndThirdWed(moment().year(), moment().month()),
  format: "ll",
  minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
}).on("dp.update", function (e) {
  if( e.viewDate ){
    var enabledDates = getFirstAndThirdWed(e.viewDate.year(), e.viewDate.month());
    $('.bootstrap-date-picker').data("DateTimePicker").enabledDates(enabledDates);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/fr.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date bootstrap-date-picker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Added [`startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) in `minDate` option to prevent problem when the current date is the first Wednesday of the month and you try to select it.

Comment: @ArthurKoenig glad to help. I've edited my answer to be sure there are no issue when the current date is the first Wednesday of the month. Don't forget to mark the asnwer as accepted (read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you need help) if the answer solved your problem.