# Countdown to a single day each year (and find the date of that day in current year)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, countdowntimer

I am looking to do something quite complex and I've been using moment.js or countdown.js to try and solve this, but I think my requirements are too complex? I may be wrong. Here is the criteria...

I need to be able to have the following achievable without having to change the dates manually each year, only add it once and have many countdowns on one page.

> 1. Find current date
> 2. Find current year
> 3. Find current month
> 4. Find day within week of month that applies
>       ¬ 3rd Sunday or 2nd Saturday
> 5. Convert to JS and output as html and run countdown
> 6. When past date - reset for following year

Pretty mental. So for example if an event is always on the 3rd Sunday of March. The date would not be the same each year.

> 1. 2016 - Sunday March 19th
> 2. 2017 - Sunday March 20th
> 3. 2018 - Sunday March 18th etc.

I hope this is explained well, I realise it may be a total mess though. I managed to get it resetting each year with the date added manually but then someone threw in the spanner of the ***date*** being different each year.

```
var event = new Date();
event = new Date(event.getFullYear() + 1, 3 - 1, 19);
jQuery('#dateEvent').countdown({ until: event });


<div id="dateEvent"></div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to get the right day.  and then you can use the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335554/determine-third-friday-of-the-month-given-month-and-year

Comment: Hi - okay that looks promising, I guess I would have to set up functions for each event though? There will be hundreds. Also I'm trying to figure out how to output the moment. I can with another timer I set up using 
var time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a'); then
$('.time').text(time);

Comment: You need only a year, a month and which interval of given day in month, the rest you can automate. If a user inputs a date, or a date is supplied from database, you can calculate which day it is, which occurence in the month it is, and create your moment.js object with that. The only thing that should be different is the "starting date" the first time such an event occurred.

Comment: Thanks @Tschallacka I added a solution in my question from where you pointed me too!

Comment: You should 'self answer' your question, that way other visitors can see the answer, and in 2 days you can accept that answer as the solution. You should not post an answer in a question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Tschallacka

Comment: Please consider give credit (e.g. upvote) to the linked answer, if it was useful to solve your issue.

Comment: Will do @Tschallacka

Comment: Ideally @Tschallacka I would like it to know the current date so it works for ever more. If I add 1 year to the moment it gets the correct date for the following year. This is impractical though...

Answer (score 1):

I have edited this answer as I have now put together a solution that works for me. As I believe this isn't simple coding due to the fact it wasn't actually answered 'Please, this is basic coding. pick up a javascript book and learn to code', yeah thanks...

```
// get the specific day of the week in the month in the year
        function getDay(month) {
            // Convert date to moment (month 0-11)
            var myMonth = moment("April", "MMMM");
            // Get first Sunday of the first week of the month
            var getDay = myMonth.weekday(0); // sunday is 0
            var nWeeks = 3; // 0 is 1st week
            // Check if first Sunday is in the given month
            if (getDay.month() != month) {
                nWeeks++;
            }
            // Return 3rd Sunday of the month formatted (custom format)
            return getDay.add(nWeeks, 'weeks').format("Y-MM-D h:mm:ss");
        }

        // print out the date as HTML and wrap in span
        document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '<span>' + getDay() + '</span>';
```

Using

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps someone - I'll update when I figure how to + 1 year after it's checked current date and event has passed. I'll look in that JS book.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the below code, I explained in the comment what what does.

You use it by supplying a javascript Date object of any wished start date, and then add as a second value the corresponding year you wish to know the date in.

```js
var date = new Date("2016-03-20");

function getDayInYear(startDate, year) {
    // get a moment instance of the start date
    var start = moment(startDate);
    // collect the moment.js values for the day and month
    var day = start.day();
    var month = start.month();
    // calculate which week in the month the date is. 
    var nthWeekOfMoth = Math.ceil(start.date() / 7);
    // Build up the new moment with a date object, passing the requested year, month and week in it
    var newMoment = moment(new Date(year,month,(nthWeekOfMoth * 7)));
    // Return the next instance of the requested day from the current newMoment date value.
    return newMoment.day(day);
}

var oldMoment = moment(date);
var newMoment2017 = getDayInYear(date,2017);
var newMoment2018 = getDayInYear(date,2018);

console.log(oldMoment.format('YYYY MMMM dddd DD'));
console.log(newMoment2017.format('YYYY MMMM dddd DD'));
console.log(newMoment2018.format('YYYY MMMM dddd DD'));

/** working from today up to 10 years into the future **/

var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    console.log(getDayInYear(date, year+i).format('YYYY MMMM dddd DD'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay this explains what's going on much better. It still requires manual date entry though which I need to avoid. I need it to know the current date and work forward year by year from that. I'll have to look through the moment.js documentation more to see if this is possible. adding document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (date); it will only show 2016 etc. where it would need to be the 2017 date now.

Comment: current date is just `var date = new Date()`

Comment: Hi @Tschallacka yes that does indeed get the current date. I need to incorporate this into the functionality of the above original stages 1 - 6. So far you have helped get the day of the month in the year which is awesome but I need to have it find it automatically for every year starting from say, today for example. pump that out as a countdown timer to the next year and then reset. I've got a long way to go I think. I don;t want to manually enter any dates apart from the original first date as the reference for the script to know what date to count down to.

Comment: see my edit, I just edited in an example that outputs the dates for this year and the next 10 years. Please, this is basic coding. pick up a javascript book and learn to code.